# Android phone calls from an application

Tags: android

In android programming, is it possible to make a phone call within a service without showing the 'phone call screen'? Any example would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, but "Thanks in advance" doesn't really work in Stack Overflow, as here you thank others by upvoting or accepting their answers.

Answer (score 4):

> In android programming, is it possible to make a phone call within a service without showing the 'phone call screen'?

That depends on what you consider the "phone call screen" to be.

If you mean the dialer, then, yes, you can use an `ACTION_CALL` `Intent` to bypass that, assuming that you hold the `CALL_PHONE` permission.

If you mean the in-call screen then, no, AFAIK there is no way to avoid that screen. That screen is rather important for the user.